# Magento orders stores customer name and email id is null

Tags: php, magento

In my magento site, few orders are created with customer_id and customer_firstname, customer_email etc (related to customer) fields are inserted with **null** values in **sales_flat_order** and **sales_flat_quote** tables.

I have checked the customers are **Registered** customers.  We have used the Appmerce-Eway extension for credit card payment.  Why & When it is stored as **null**?  If anyone knows, guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The extension could have an error or maybe some parts of it are overwritten by other extensions. You can check if the version of the extension is compatible with the version of your system. You can see this if you log into magento connect in the backend.